# Internalization UTF-16 application on Windows (using gettext or an alternative)

Tags: c++, winapi, internationalization, gettext, utf-16

I have an application written in C++ which uses WTL for GUI (a library similar to MFC, generally a winapi wrapper), `CString` class and Win32 "Wide API". 
I want to translate it in different languages. My program tends to be cross-platform so I decided to use available opensource solutions instead of reinventing a wheel.
But the gettext library lacks support for wide strings:

```
char* gettext (const char *__msgid);
char* dgettext (const char *__domainname, const char *__msgid);
char* ngettext (const char *__msgid1, const char *__msgid2, unsigned long int __n);
```

Is there a way to use this library without re-encoding from utf-8 to utf-16 and vice-versa on each call? It may affect performance.

Also gettext seems to lack support for positional parameters (like Qt does have).

By the way, can i use custom macros with gettext? for example, _("") for utf-8 string and __("") for utf-16 strings ?

Maybe there is a better approach? Or a better library?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: There will be no perf issue. Use gettext.

Comment: By the way, can I use custom macros with gettext? For example, `_("")` for utf-8 strings and `__("")` for utf-16 strings ? Gettext tools have such an option?

Comment: You can use whatever macros you like

Comment: The performance issue you'll hit first is allocating heap memory. In comparison, the conversion between encodings fades into statistical noise.